# momentjs how to format as 21h:31m

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I want to convert from seconds to hours and minutes in the following format:

```
21h:31m
28h:40m
20m
5h
```

I don't want to display seconds nor days, and don't display 0h:30m (only 30m instead) and don't display 1h:0m (only 1h)

is there any way to format this with momentjs?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [momentjs docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) for duration time.

You can put in a time in seconds (`moment.duration(60*60*48+5*60, "seconds")`) and then run some code to format it for you:

```
var time = moment.duration(60*60*48+5*60, "seconds");
var hours = Math.floor(time.asHours());
var minutes = time.minutes();
var timeString = "";
if (hours > 0) {
  timeString += hours + "h";
}
if (hours > 0 && minutes > 0) {
  timeString += ":";
}
if (minutes >= 10) {
  timeString += minutes + "m";
} else if (minutes > 0) {
  timeString += "0" + minutes + "m";
}
```